# unicode issue in R and RGtk2

Tags: r, unicode, gtk, locale

I am using R and RGtk2 package to create a GUI for data entry of english and non-ACSII strings (most of them are Chinese), data will be stored as a dataframe. I built a prototype and tried, but found something interesting:

- when I view the dataframe using head(df), it is scrambled in R console (Rgui) and in RStudio's console
- when the dataframe is viewed using View(df), it is normal for RStudio, but again scrambled in R console
- I use write.table(df,"foo.txt") to export the dataframe, it is presented normally in notepad++
- I can type the Chinese normally in gtkTextEntry object, but after it is saved and loaded into the same gtkTextEntry object, the text is scrambled

I wonder what caused the problem: R locale settings; my win7's regional settings; GTK+ runtime, or RGtk2 itself, I heard about something like g_convert in GTK+, I wonder if it can help, if yes, how to use that in R?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
Encoding(df[,"col"]) <- "UTF-8"
```

This converts the `df[,"col"]` column.